В одной переменной много строк, как каждую поместить в одну строку
После цикла For заключил в одну переменную несколько выводов, как сделать чтобы был один класс у переменной?
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
...

res_products_json = res_products.json()['result']['products']
data_by_user = {}
for d in res_products_json:
    data_by_user[d["final"]] = d
    productName = d["productName"]
    str_num = d["final"]
    int_num = int(str_num)
    if int_num < 10:
        final = str(int_num)
        data = productName + '\n' + 'Осталось мало:' + final + '\n'


Уточню, сделать так чтобы все эти значения, были  в одной строке

Пока ничего не понятно. В какой переменной, при чём тут вывод класса str, вместо значений и в чём проблема конкатенировать строки, если нужно сделать одной большой?

переменная data. при каждой итерации я получаю много выводов, и их надо переслать в ТГ бота одним сообщением, Конкатенация тут не причем, так как это значение одной переменной

До цикла lst = [], в цикле lst.append(data), после цикла all_data = ''.join(lst); print(all_data)

Если мой ответ вам помог, то вы можете отметить его как правильный (Галочка около ответа)

Возможно, это то, что вам нужно
res_products_json = res_products.json()['result']['products']
data_by_user = {}
res = []
for d in res_products_json:
    data_by_user[d["final"]] = d
    productName = d["productName"]
    str_num = d["final"]
    int_num = int(str_num)
    if int_num < 10:
        final = str(int_num)
        res.append(productName + '\n' + 'Осталось мало:' + final)

print("\n".join(res))


Если это не то, что вы ищете, то лучше прикрепить к вопросу полный код (Кнопка "Править" под вопросом)

К сожалению нет, все ровно в переменной храниться все значения из цикла, а мне нужно сделать, чтобы все они стали единой строкой

Вам нужно чтобы все значчения переменной остались в этой переменной, но уже как одна строка? Не совсем понятно, что вам нужно, можете ли вы переформулировать вопрос? Так же соглашусь с  mrBars1k, при чем тут str?

Да все верно, все итерации которые были в data class str это print(type(data)) и как мы видим их много и выводов также, все разные, но хотелось бы, чтобы они стали единой строкой, то есть при print(type(data)) условно был один вывод <class 'str'>

Отредактировал вопрос, может это то, что вам надо?
